# High Bandwidth vs Low Latency?

Tags: language-agnostic, networking

[Google FileSystem Paper](http://labs.google.com/papers/gfs.html) -

> High sustained bandwidth is more important than low latency. Most of our target applications place a premium on processing data in bulk at a high rate, while few have stringent response time requirements for an individual read or write.

Wouldn't having a high sustained bandwidth automatically guarantee low latency?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not necessarily.  For example, an airplane filled with backup tapes flying from one side of the continent to the other has very high bandwidth because it gets all of the data there before any existing network could.  However, it has very high latency because each individual piece of data took a very long time to get there.

Bandwidth is important when you have a lot of data to send/receive and it doesn't really need to be real-time, such as transferring large amounts of data to an off-site backup.  (You don't really care in what order the data arrives or how quickly the other side can respond, you just need all the data to get there.)

Latency is important when timing is critical in how/when the data arrives, such as online gaming or video streaming.  (You don't care how much data may have been dropped as long as the "current" packet is arriving "right now.")

Obligatory:  "Never underestimate the bandwidth of a station wagon full of tapes hurtling down the highway." —Tanenbaum, Andrew S. (1996)

(The first Google hit on this quote was the Wikipedia page for [Sneakernet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sneakernet), which is another excellent example of high bandwidth and high latency.)

(Or, in my case about a month ago, the bandwidth of a Scion carrying 2 TB hard drives down the highway.  I transferred 15 TB of data in two days.  Not bad for consumer-grade hardware.)

Comment: You must mean very high latency.

Comment: @larsmans: Corrected, thanks.  I always mess that up for some reason.  It's like I'm conditioned to assume high = good and low = bad.

Comment: +1, although note the question says high *sustained* bandwidth, so you need to make that a regular flight. The postal service has high sustained bandwidth (well, during working hours it does), it's receiving and delivering things all the time. But it still has a latency of at best a day or so even within a city. A motorcycle courier service achieves lower latency, but lower bandwidth basically because unlike the postal service it doesn't wait for a truck full of stuff all going in the same general direction.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Another good example.  I'm now picturing the latency of a fleet of bicycle-riding fast food delivery boys in a city.  They can get anywhere fast, but they don't carry much.  I'm also reminded of a few years ago when my employer needed to transfer 800 GB to a remote office.  After a day of IT trying to explain to upper management that they couldn't do it in under at least a week, I overheard them and suggested they just FedEx a drive with the data.  Worked out just fine.

Comment: @David: we briefly improved on the performance of Sneakernet with the Frisbeenet protocol, but USB sticks just don't have the aerodynamic properties of floppies or CDs, so it couldn't keep up in the long run.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Worth a try, but the frequency of dropped packets would kill the network in that case.  And God help you on packet collisions along the wire.

Comment: The worst problem with Frisbeenet was misdelivery, actually. You'd think that nearby nodes would easily be able to re-send a packet not addressed to them, but it often didn't work out that way when the node was not actively prepared for input at the time. Sometimes the node would even malfunction to the extent of re-addressing the packet to sender instead of final destination! This was solved by using a lower-bandwidth broadcast-capable transport layer to pre-announce Frisbeenet packets.